# How to create nested dictionaries from a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this example and want to transform it into a list of python dictionaries with nested dictionaries. I need this format to process the data with a given API.

Basically it should convert some columns to a dict per row and some column for the address to a nested dict with the address details.

Sample DF

| Name | Last Name | Street | City | Postcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | Milky Way 1 | Star City | 31415 |
| Jim | Beam | Moonshine Rd 8 | Sin City | 12345 |
| Joe | Biden | 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW | Washington, D.C. | 20500 |

Sample list of dicts

```
lst = [{'Name': 'John',
        'Last Name': 'Doe',
        'Address': {'Street': 'Milky Way 1',
                    'City': 'Star City',
                    'Postcode': '31415'}},
       {'Name': 'Jim', 
        'Last Name': 'Beam',
        'Address': {'Street': 'Moonshine Rd 8',
                    'City': 'Sin City',
                    'Postcode': '12345'}},
       {'Name': 'Joe',
        'Last Name': 'Biden',
        'Address': {'Street': '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW',
                    'City': 'Washington, D.C.',
                    'Postcode': '20500'}},
      ]
```

Reading through other posts, I found the opposite process (to convert dicts with nested dicts to a Pandas data frame) but that is not what I need. I also read that you should not iterate through the rows of a pandas data frame, but that is what I usually would try as I am new to pandas.

Is there a more elegant way to use pandas tools and group columns?

Comment: Please double check your input, it's invalid python (you haven't closed the curly brackets)

Comment: Do you need a Python dictionary or a JSON? If you want the latter, use @Quang Hoang's answer with `.to_json('records')` in place of `.to_dict('records')`. This results in a string according to the JSON spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the `Address` first, then you can use `to_dict`:

```
(df.set_index(['Name', 'Last Name']).agg(pd.Series.to_dict, axis=1)
   .to_frame('Address')
   .reset_index()
   .to_dict('records')
)
```

Outout:

```
[{'Name': 'John',
  'Last Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': {'Street': 'Milky Way 1',
   'City': 'Star City',
   'Postcode': 31415}},
 {'Name': 'Jim',
  'Last Name': 'Beam',
  'Address': {'Street': 'Moonshine Rd 8',
   'City': 'Sin City',
   'Postcode': 12345}},
 {'Name': 'Joe',
  'Last Name': 'Biden',
  'Address': {'Street': '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW',
   'City': 'Washington, D.C.',
   'Postcode': 20500}}]
```

Comment: Is there a way to skip cells that have a NaN? So only add cells tot he nested dict if they have a value ? For example if the ZIP code is empty I don't want to update it, hence I don't want to have it on the dictionary.

Comment: Use `.agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for you support. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

To convert from DataFrame to list of dictionaries you can use a list comprehension and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
group = ['Name', 'Last Name']

out = [dict(zip(group, k))|{'Adress': g.squeeze().to_dict()}
       for k, g in df.set_index(group).groupby(level=group)]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'John',
 'Last Name': 'Doe',
 'Address': {'Street': 'Milky Way 1',
             'City': 'Star City',
             'Postcode': '31415'}},
 {'Name': 'Jim', 
  'Last Name': 'Beam',
  'Address': {'Street': 'Moonshine Rd 8',
              'City': 'Sin City',
              'Postcode': '12345'}},
 {'Name': 'Joe',
  'Last Name': 'Biden',
  'Address': {'Street': '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW',
              'City': 'Washington, D.C.',
              'Postcode': '20500'}},
  ]
```

For the reverse operation, use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and optionally [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns:

```
out = pd.json_normalize(lst).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
```

Output:

```
   Name Last Name                       Street              City Postcode
0  John       Doe                  Milky Way 1         Star City    31415
1   Jim      Beam               Moonshine Rd 8          Sin City    12345
2   Joe     Biden  1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW  Washington, D.C.    20500
```

Comment: lol, we go in different direction. but I think I'm correct since _ it should convert some columns to a dict per row_

Comment: @Quang oh you're right, I got lost with the original incorrect formatting of the question. I fixed it ;)